# Database connectivity succeeds but unable to run query

Tags: python, postgresql

I am able to connect Python 3.4 and Postgres but I am the query is not successfully getting executed. For e.g, the table below is not getting created

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import connect 


try:
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres'")
print("Database connected!")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY      NOT NULL,
DEPT           CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
EMP_ID         INT      NOT NULL
)""")
except:
print("I am unable to connect to the database")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
conn.commit()
```

after you've run the `execute`.

Relational databases have the concept of **transaction**, which happen (if at all) "atomically" (all-or-none).  You need to `commit` a transaction to actually make it take place; until you've done that, you keep the option to `rollback` it instead, to have no changes made to the DB if you've found something iffy on the way.

Comment: You're welcome, so what about an accept (clic the checkmark-shaped outline to the left of my answer)?